# Write another line at the end of GROOVY sql write

Tags: sql, groovy

The code below rights each line in my SQL.  Is there a way to right a single line at the end of the SQL write?  What is that syntax?  Something like "This report was run July 1st 2013 by User John Doe".

```
db.eachRow(sql) {
    def desc = it.summary
    desc = desc.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "")
    file.append(it.CHANGEID + "\t" + it.REGION + "\t" + it.DIVISION + "\t" + desc + "\t" + "\n")
    }
```

Comment: `isLast` from [GroovyResultSet](http://groovy.codehaus.org/api/groovy/sql/GroovyResultSet.html) should suffice, right?

Answer (score 1):

```
db.eachRow(sql) {
  ....
  if(it.isLast()){
     //Append custom text to file.
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You mean

```
String user = 'tim' // for example

new File( 'output.txt' ).withWriter { w ->
  db.eachRow(sql) {
    def desc = it.summary
    desc = desc.replaceAll("[\r\n]", "")
    w.writeLine( "$it.CHANGEID\t$it.REGION\t$it.DIVISION\t$desc" )
  }
  w.writeLine( "written by $user on ${new Date()}" )
}
```